# Xamarin Forms Trim MP3 Files

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm trying to use Naudio to cut the file but i have issue at reading the file

> Could not find a part of the path "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Titanic-Orchestra-My-Heart-Will-Go-On.mp3/Titanic-Orchestra-My-Heart-Will-Go-On.mp3".

my code is

```
        string[] fileTypes = null;
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
            fileTypes = new string[] { "audio/mpeg", "audio/mpeg3", "audio/x-mpeg3","audio/aac", "audio/wav", "audio/ogg", "audio/midi", "audio/x-ms-wma", "audio/wma" };
        //FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
        //string fileName = fileData.FileName;

        FileData da = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(fileTypes);
        string fileName2 = da.FileName;
        string filepath = da.FilePath;

        string output = da.FilePath.Replace(fileName2, "") + "/";
        string input = filepath + "/" + fileName2;

        TrimWavFile(input, output , TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

public static void TrimWavFile(string inPath, string outPath, TimeSpan cutFromStart, TimeSpan cutFromEnd)
{
    using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(inPath))
    {
        using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outPath, reader.WaveFormat))
        {
            int bytesPerMillisecond = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 1000;

            int startPos = (int)cutFromStart.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond;
            startPos = startPos - startPos % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;

            int endBytes = (int)cutFromEnd.TotalMilliseconds * bytesPerMillisecond;
            endBytes = endBytes - endBytes % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;
            int endPos = (int)reader.Length - endBytes;

            TrimWavFile2(reader, writer, startPos, endPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cfun Yup i tried that one and i got that path ("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/1C1E-1713%3AMy%20Heart%20Will%20Go%20On.wav")
but i got the same error couldn't find

Comment: https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows#important

Comment: @Jason i got invalid carracter issue too is there another way to get file picker coz i think this plugin dead ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker

Comment: @Cfun it works thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

As that package seems to be not maintained anymore, you can use [FilePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker) from [Xamarin.Essential](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/) package which is officially maintained by Microsoft.